# How to revive a stored car?

Tags: corolla, long-term-storage

A 2010 Corolla was sitting idle for a year; before that it was running fine. Naturally, the battery is dead. What should I do, besides replacing battery and washing the spider webs off? Also, can I jump start and drive to the mechanic on a dead battery?

Comment: If it had no major problems before, jumping the battery should be the only thing you need to do to get it running. Maybe change the oil as it might decompose over time. Maybe check the tires for flat spots and dry cracks

Comment: Depending upon how crufty the interior got during its year in time-out, you may want to hire a detailer to give it a good, solid cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

Mechanically it's probably fine, other than checking the fluids and maybe pouring some fresh fuel into the tank replacing the battery is likely all you have to do, other than giving it a really good inspection to make sure there aren't animals nesting in it somewhere.